# Adding margin to table makes it overflow the parent

Tags: css

I have a page which expands as the number of columns in the table increase. As long as I don't add a margin to the `div` containing the table, the page table doesn't overflow the parent. But when I add a `margin-left:2px` to the `div` containing the table, it overflows the parent. How can this be avoided?

```css
.canvas{
    margin-left: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 60%;
}
.canvas .column-table {
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas">
    <div class="column-table">
        <table id="main-table">
            <tr id="row1">
            </tr>
            <tr id="row2">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow: hidden` to your canvas class? It should do it, as it has a `min-width` set.

Comment: Instead we guess for a answer to your problem. You need to show us a working example of your problem. Can you put this in a codepen or jsfiddle for us to figure out that your issue is. Thanks.

Comment: it will be better to have a demo with plunkr or fiddle

Comment: @GuilhermeP : Adding overfow: hidden worked. Thnx

Comment: No problem. Glad it did it

Answer (score 1):

Using `box-sizing: border-box;` should solve this, I believe:

```css
.canvas {
    margin-left: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 60%;
}
.canvas .column-table {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

If not, try `box-sizing: content-box;`

Comment: It didn't solve. I think the problem is the parent page is not able to expand enough for the last column.

Comment: Do you have a URL where we can see it?